# SFML title bar with weird characters when using UTF-8

Tags: c++, sfml

(Previously asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922478/sfml-title-bar-with-weird-characters-when-using-utf-8)

I've just started using SFML and one of the first problems I've come across is some weird characters on the the titlebar whenever I try to use accents or any other extended char.

For instance, I've got:

```
sf::RenderWindow Ventana(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Año nuevóóó");
```

And the titlebar renders like `AÂ+o nuevoA³A³A³`

This ONLY HAPPENS if my source code file is enconded in UTF-8. If I change the file encoding to ISO-8859-1, it shows properly. Obviously all of my files use UTF-8, as its the system-wide encoding. I'm using GCC under Ubuntu GNU/Linux.

I've tried using the different utilities in `sf::Unicode` to adapt the text, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: This isn't really game development related, though I see you came here after receiving no response from SO after two days... Have you tried the SFML forums? http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/

Comment: One of the problems in debugging problems like this is that the issue can lie anywhere from passing the wrong -fexec-charset to GCC to your window manager implementing Unicode conversion incorrectly. The best approach is usually to break out a debugger and step through as much as you need to to see what failed.

Answer (score 2):

IF your source code file is in UTF-8 then those non-ASCII characters can be represented by more than one byte. eg. 'ó' is represented by 'A³' (or perhaps more accurately, 'ó' is represented by values that render as 'A³'). I think you should be very careful when using UTF-8 source files since C++ string literals imply 1 byte per character but UTF-8 characters break that assumption. I'd recommend switching to a fixed-width representation like ISO-8859-1 for your source files.

The SFML RenderWindow constructor takes a "const std::string &Title" - this has no encoding specified, but it gets passed through to a WindowImpl class which decides how to pass the string to the OS. It looks like Win32 makes an attempt at handling Unicode, but I don't have the Unix/X code to hand. I suggest looking through that and seeing if it does something similar. Either way, the std::string carries no encoding information at all so it's risky to use anything but ASCII, unless SFML explicitly states what kind of text encoding to supply.